# Password regex string in strings.xml file in android

Tags: android, regex, xml, string

I have declared a regex for password validation purposes in strings.xml file.
The criteria is

-should be atleast 8 characters
-should contain atleast one upper case letter
-should contain atleast one lower case letter
-should contain atleast one special character within these "@#$%^+&="

So my whole regex looks like this now

^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^+&=])(?=\S+$).{8,}$

But when I enter this, I get an error saying that & is

"Unescaped or non terminated character entity/reference"

So instead I used the escape sequence as & but the validation fails for &
I would b glad if anyone could help me out on this!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `*` quantifers in the look-aheads. Right now, you check if 2nd character in the string meets your conditions. We need to test them all in the string.

```
  ^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^+&=])(?=\S+$).{8,}$
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hC8rT6/1).

**EDIT**

Since the regex is located inside the XML code, it should be properly encoded. Or, use it inside `CDATA` block.

Comment: Not in the look aheads. `.` means just 1 symbol but a newline.

Comment: E.g `^(?=.[0-9])` will only test the first two characters.  The rest will not be tested against your condition.

Comment: E.g `^(?=.[0-9])` will only test the first two characters. The rest will not be tested against your condition. I added a link to a working example: https://regex101.com/r/hC8rT6/1.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work on the Android flavour, I still get the & as unescaped error.. Is this a particular issue with Android..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74697/discussion-between-stribizhev-and-user3747512).

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a parameter in your curly braces? The last bit "{8,}" seems off.

Comment: well, that is fine, it just says that the minimum length is 8 and doesn't specify the maximum length

Comment: @LeeFrone: You should have a look at **Limiting Repetition** at http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html. `{1,} is the same as +`. `{N,}` is a valid pattern.